# In Squirrel, how can I duplicate a row?

Tags: squirrel-sql

In a tool like SQL Developer, I can right click on a row and select duplicate to get a copy of row, edit it, and commit it. How can I do this in Squirrel? I don't even see how to add a new row in the Content view.

Answer (score 15):

Found a way to insert rows, though not duplicate. In the Content view, right-click and choose "Make editable" (I thought this just applied to the selected row). Right-click again and now there is an "Insert Row" option. A popup appears for entering the values for each field of the new row.

Comment: Ok, you can RMB and select 'select entire row' and then RMB 'Copy as SQL INSERT-VALUES statement'. Then you can go to SQL tab, paste the copied statement and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. That's less than an ideal but a decent way to do it.

Comment: You're right - it would be great if there would be any clickable way to duplicate a row. Unfortunately when I click 'insert new row' all columns are empty by default. In case of many columns, it's hard to type all values by the hand, so then I use 'INSERT-VALUES' script. Nevertheless - Squirrel is great! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to duplicate.
You have to do following:

1. select one row with the context menu entry "Select entire row(s)" or all rows with "Select All"
2. In the context menu, select "Copy as SQL INSERT-VALUES statement"
3. Paste the copied content in the sql tab editor

Done